# In need of iterating and modifying arraylist (or similar) at the same time

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to iterate over a list that is being modified elsewhere at the same time, which I read is not possible with ArrayList..

Does anyone have a tip on what I can use? Or if this is possible? Doing arraycopy and such I think will be to slow for my needs but if there is no other alternative I'll look into that. Anyways, hope for another tip :)

Code

```
Iterator<blabla> haha = bytes.iterator();
while(haha.hasNext()) {
  blabla aStorage = haha.next();
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(120); 
}
```

and elsewhere

```
bytes.add(aStorage);
```

Comment: your code please

Comment: *I think will be to slow*: don't think. Measure.

Comment: Please post some code to illustrate, it's hard to know what you need with the informations you posted. Modified how, where exactly, etc

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html maybe?

Comment: @YCF_L added some code :)

Comment: @JBNizet I will do :)

Comment: @RC. added some code :)

Comment: @luk2302 thanks I will check it out

Comment: You sleep 120 milliseconds at each iteration of your loop, and copying the list would be too slow? You probably can make hundreds of copies of your list in less than 1 millisecond.

Comment: looking at your code it looks like you want a Queue, not a list. Maybe [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) helps?

Comment: @JBNizet this code is only for you as example.  I change and add. and original has sleep but far from 120ms. But ok, maybe arraycopy could work..

Comment: And sortof only mentioned no arraycopy because I already knew about it.. But that linked que seems to be sort of what I need. Thanks @Dennux

Comment: But I do not get the arraycopy, how will that work when then the whole list is modified? I think the only thing working for me would be the concurrentlinkedqueue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll move my comment into an answer.

> looking at your code it looks like you want a Queue, not a list. Maybe [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) helps?

Here is a very simple example of how the Queue works:

```
private final static Queue<String> myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Adder()).start();
    new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
}

private static class Adder implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            myQueue.add(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class Consumer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            for (String value = myQueue.poll(); value != null; value = myQueue.poll()) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at [The Javadoc for the Queue Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and maybe take a look at the [Official Collections Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) which is a very good source to find the fitting abstract datatype for your need. It's always good to know more Collections than Lists.

Some of the Collections i use on a regular basis:

- List (ArrayList, LinkedList)
- Set (HashSet, TreeSet)
- Map (HashMap)
- Queue (LinkedList, ConcurrentLinkedQueue)

Comment: Thank you :)

I tried the que solution and it worked. But seems something is very out of order. I tried polling first, but that gave a nullpointer.. now I iterate over the queue and it works, but the data order or data itself has been manipulated as it is not the same results as with iterating over a arraylist.

Comment: The ConcurrentLinkedQueue gives out the elements in the order you put them in (First-in-first-out Principle). So the order of the elements should be the same as when you call list.add(). But keep in mind the poll() Method gets the first element in the queue and removes it. That's what a queue is for. If you iterate over the elements in a queue, they wont be removed (like with the peek() method).

Comment: Okey. I understand. I will se if I have misplaced any buffervales or if the data is corrupted, Thank you for this and the other info :) This is what I was looking for!